# How to export vectors into a text file such that POVray can read them?

Tags: export

I have a list of vectors in Mathematica which I want to write into a text file such that POVray can read them as vectors. 
The list of vectors looks something like this:
`H = {{3,3,3,3},{4,4,4,4},{5,5,5,5}}`
I know that I can use
`Export["filename.txt", H, "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> "," ];`
to have the output file look like the following:
`3,3,3,3`
`4,4,4,4`
`5,5,5,5`
I also know that POVray recognizes vectors as `<3,3,3,3>`.
My question now is,
is there some rule that works the same as FieldSeperators (maybe something like BeginOfLineSeperators and EndOfLineSeperators) such that i can get the output file to have rows like `<3,3,3,3>` instead of `3,3,3,3`?
Or is there any other way of doing this easily?

All help is appreciated

Comment: About how many vectors are you looking at? This shouldn't be too hard, but if you have tons of them the performance might need thinking about.

Comment: My real lists contains 20 vectors for now, but I will also be using an instance where my list contains 2400 vectors. So it differs.

Comment: The posted solution by creidhne will definitely work fine for either case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ExportString` in place of `Export`, replace the start and end of each line to form POV lists, and then export to a text file.

```
txt = ExportString[H, "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> ","];
pov = StringReplace[txt, {StartOfLine -> "<", EndOfLine -> ">"}];
Export["lists.pov", pov, "Text"]
```